# Submap() of TreeMap behavior when a Comparator is used

Tags: java, collections, treemap

I am working on a TreeMap. When I run this piece of code, it gives me the desired result.

```
TreeMap<String, Integer> dept = new TreeMap<>();

dept.put("Testing", 1);
dept.put("Training", 2);
dept.put("Automation", 3);
dept.put("Web Development", 4);
dept.put("Progamming", 5);
dept.put("Sales", 6);
dept.put("Housekeeping", 7);

SortedMap<String, Integer> subDept = dept.subMap("Sales","Training\0");

subDept.forEach( (name, id) -> System.out.println(name + " -> " +  id));
```

> **Output**: Sales -> 6 Testing -> 1 Training -> 2

Now, I have changed the TreeMap to take a Comparator and tried getting a submap.

```
TreeMap<String, Integer> dept = new TreeMap<>(Comparator.reverseOrder());
SortedMap<String, Integer> subDept = dept.subMap("Training", "Sales\0");
```

But, I get the result as

> Training -> 2 Testing -> 1

and not

> Training -> 2 Testing -> 1 Sales -> 6

Why doesn't appending \0 to the second parameter of submap make it a closed range when a reversed comparator is used? Or, am I missing something in the code?

Comment: With `TreeMap` (or any `NavigableMap`), why not use [the overload of `subMap` which takes the explicit inclusivity parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#subMap-K-boolean-K-boolean-)?

Comment: I know it can be used. This code is merely for my exercise and wanted to know if I am missing any of the reasoning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a reversed ordering, `"Sales\0"` comes before `"Sales"`.

Appending `\0` is a hack that only works for strings, and only for strings in lexicographic order. For this case, you'd have to change the string to something that lexicographically precedes `Sales`, e.g. `Saler`.

A far easier and more robust approach would be to use the provided method for getting a closed range:

```
dept.subMap("Training", true, "Sales", true)
```